# How to get Ansible variable base on extra-var

Tags: ansible

roles/var/main.yaml

```
WEST: 
    State:CA
    Capital: Sacramento
EAST
   State: NY
   Capital: NY
```

My ansible command

```
ansible-playbook -i host -l nodes -e SITE=WEST mytestplaybook.yaml <br/>
```

So base on that how can I get Sacrament as a variable?
I tried `{{ SITE.Capital }}` which doesn't work.

If I don't use `extra-var`, I am able to get value, (ie `ansible-playbook -i host -l nodes mytestplaybook.yaml`) where `{{ WEST.Capital }}` gives Sacramento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are setting `SITE` to a string value. It is not a dictionary/hash and so cannot be referenced in that way. You would need to substitute the variable name first, like this:

```
    - debug:
        var: "{{ SITE }}.Capital"
```

However this does not work in all situations, due to the way string interpolation works in Ansible/Jinja2.

To achieve your goal, there are a couple of approaches...

**Approach 1**, using the same extra variable input:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vars[SITE]['Capital'] }}"
```

**Approach 2**, updating your extra variable input to be assigned the dictionary value (instead of just a string value):

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "SITE={{ WEST }}"
```

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ SITE.Capital }}"
```